# How to avoid the "Open IME" popup in a StringGrid?

Tags: delphi, ime

In a StringGrid, sometimes I get the unwanted menu below when I right-click. Is this a Windows popup?

[image: popup screen capture]

How to I prevent this popup from appearing rather than my own?

I have goAlwaysShowEditor in my Options.

I have set StringGrid.PopupMenu to my popup.

I've set StringGrid.OnMouseDown to show my popup if it's a right click.

Comment: Are you trying to hurt your users? Why shouldn't they open IME?

Comment: @David Hefferman: "Why shouldn't they open IME?" Because I want to add additional menu options to the right-click menu when the user is in this grid.  I ended up taking my cue from Excel's pop-up,  which has only Cut, Copy, Paste but not the Unicode stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the virtual `CreateEditor` method like this way (not a good solution though, I know :-):

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

implementation

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited CreateEditor;
  TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := Form1.PopupMenu1;
end;
```

Comment: TLama: one problem with this approach: if my program changes the column (i.e. StringGrid.Col := 2;)  the InplaceEditor doesn't open, and the I-bar isn't visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: This should work wherever you try to edit the cell. I've updated the post so to respect the inheritance (what should be there anyway). Now the only weakness (from two lines of code :-) is the `TInplaceEdit` class typecast, because it depends on what type the `TInplaceEdit` inherits from. In Delphi 2009 it's from the `TCustomMaskEdit`, for what the nearest class descendant where the `PopupMenu` property is published is `TMaskEdit`, that's why it's typecasted as it is.

Comment: For anyone else who might encounter this in the future: I was changing the current column from a different form. I was already changing the focus to the form with the StringGrid, and to the StringGrid control itself. But, for some reason, I found I also had to put a line StringGrid.InplaceEditor.SetFocus.  It works now. Thanks again, TLama. I REALLY appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

That is the popup menu found in every Windows EDIT control. Possible the world's most known menu (the only competition comes from the system menu). You *want* it, because your user's *expect* it (and *need* it). When you edit the text in a cell, the `TStringGrid` control actually creates a standard Windows EDIT control, which is great. And thus you get its popup menu.

In addition, to show your own popup menu (when you are not editing a cell), you don't need to set the `OnMouseDown` handler. It is enough to set the `PopupMenu` property. In fact, it is very bad to use the `OnMouseDown` handler to trigger a popup menu, because then the menu will only be shown when the user right-clicks the control (and not, for instance, when he presses the "context" button on his keyboard).

If you really want your own popup menu to show, even when the user is editing a cell, you really have to give him his usual options for undo, copy, cut, paste, Unicode stuff, etc., manually. Surely you don't want that?

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reminder. I'm so habituated to Ctrl-C, Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V that I completely forgot the copy, cut, paste functionality the many users expect. And, thanks for pointing out that I don't need OnMouseDown for the popup to work.