# How to untangle 2 components whose constructors depend on each other?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10676831/797744) to force my own `TPopupMenu` over the standard windows "Cut/Copy/Paste" context menu. The problem is I don't know how to lay out the OO structure to allow this.

```
unit BaseRamEditor.pas
type
  { This will override the default TStringGrid. }
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

  TfrmBaseRamEditor = class(TForm)
    sgrSync: TStringGrid;
    RamEdPopup: TPopupMenu;

    procedure MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
{ Use our TPopupMenu instead of Windows default. }
begin
  Result := inherited CreateEditor;
  // XXX: I don't know how to reference the `RamEdPopup` object that belongs to
  // `TfrmBaseRamEditor`. I can't reference the `TfrmBaseRamEditor` instance
  // because it hasn't been created yet because it depends on THIS new
  // `TStringGrid`.
  TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := RamEdPopup;
end;
```

Here is the `RamEdPopup` defined in the `BaseRamEditor.dfm`. Notice that the `OnClick` references a *method* of `TfrmBaseRamEditor`:

```
BaseRamEditor.dfm
=================
object frmBaseRamEditor: TfrmBaseRamEditor
    object RamEdPopup: TPopupMenu
        object MenuItem1: TMenuItem
            Caption = 'Diagramm 1'
            OnClick = MenuItem1Click
        end
    end
end
```

So the overview is:

1. The `TfrmBaseRamEditor` constructor depends on the overridden `TStringGrid`
2. This `TStringGrid` constructor depends on the `TPopupMenu` of `TfrmBaseRamEditor`.
3. This `TPopupMenu` points to the methods of `TfrmBaseRamEditor`.

How can I untangle this mess so that the `TStringGrid` used in `frmBaseRamEditor` uses the `TPopupMenu`?

Comment: Overcomplicating things you are. The TStringGrid has a PopupMenu property that you can use.

Comment: @Peter I know it has, but I must use the method of the linked answer, because if I only set `TStringGrid.PopupMenu` then left click inside a cell to edit some text, then right-click: the context menu will be the standard Windows one not my own `TPopupMenu`. My `TPopupMenu` would only show if I deselect the cell (i.e. click elsewhere) then right-click the cell.

Comment: Does `TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := TfrmBaseRamEditor(Self.Owner).RamEdPopup;` work?

Comment: @LURD Wow, yes it does. I didn't know you can make references like that; that's really cool! Many thanks for helping me

Comment: You say that the constructors depend on each other, but you haven't shown any constructors in your code. I understand how the form's constructor relies on the grid (since the form loads the DFM and creates its children, thus constructing a grid control), but I don't see how the grid's constructor would rely on the form.

Comment: @RobKennedy When our `TStringGrid` is created `CreateEditor()` is run; in this method a reference had to be made to the TPopupMenu defined in our form: that's how the grid depends on the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the owner of the `TStringGrid` (the TfrmBaseRamEditor) as the reference and typecast it to the form to access the `RamEdPopup` object:

```
TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := TfrmBaseRamEditor(Self.Owner).RamEdPopup;
```

If you want to check the cast at runtime, use the `as` intrinsic:

```
TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := (Self.Owner as TfrmBaseRamEditor).RamEdPopup;
```

Comment: Could you explain why the typecast is necessary? Without it I get compiler error: "Undeclared identifier: RamEdPopup"

Comment: Without the typecast, the owner is just a any `TComponent`, with no knowledge of the `TfrmBaseRamEditor` specifics. In this case, you know that the owner is `TfrmBaseRamEditor` and the cast is ok.

Comment: `Owner` has compile time type of `TComponent`. But the run time type is a more derived class. I'd prefer to see `as` used here to check the casts at run time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes that is probably the best thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can create additional property in your `TStringGrid` which will allow you to set editor popup menu:

```
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  protected
    FEditorPopup: TPopupMenu;
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
    procedure SetEditorPopup(Value: TPopupMenu);
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  published
    property EditorPopup: TPopupMenu read FEditorPopup write SetEditorPopup;
  end;

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited CreateEditor;
  TMaskEdit(Result).PopupMenu := FEditorPopup;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.SetEditorPopup(Value: TPopupMenu);
begin
  if Value <> FEditorPopup then
    begin
      if Assigned(FEditorPopup) then FEditorPopup.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);
      FEditorPopup := Value;
      if Assigned(FEditorPopup) then FEditorPopup.FreeNotification(Self);
      if Assigned(InplaceEditor) then TMaskEdit(InplaceEditor).PopupMenu := FEditorPopup;
    end;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited Notification(AComponent, Operation);
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FEditorPopup) then EditorPopup := nil;
end;
```

Since you are creating inplace replacement for default `TStringGrid` class, approach with published property and setting `EditorPopup` at design time may not work for you, but nothing stops you from setting `EditorPopup` property in `FormCreate` event, before user can start using string grid.